# Block my smA10 pro with IMEI

Tags: wifi-password

I wish to block phone Samsung galaxy  A10 pro with IMEI. The phone was stolen. I don't want the end user or thief to have access to my data. Also to render the useless and unuseable.

Answer (score 0):

IMEI blacklisting is done by cellular service  providers, not by users. That said, the phone can still be used barring the functions which require cellular services. Your approach with IMEI blocking/blacklisting won't do any good to your data because it has no bearing on data.

If you had Find my Google enabled you can use it to remotely wipe data (subjected to the device connected to internet). If you are a user of a US based cellular service provider, they might be offering a service to report a stolen device for IMEI blacklisting.